# Mirroring Server in EPiServer

Tags: .net, episerver

Anybody knows what properties are available as folder names when using Mirroring Service to HTML in EPiServer 4? (Dont know if this is different from newer versions)

When using the 'PageName' property the service breaks because the length of the fully quilified directory path exceeds 260 characters (Limited by the Windows filesystem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is the limitation in Windows system. That is why I always put all EpiServer websites in C:/projects/sites/YourSiteName/src/

You should never put sites in /Document and Settings/.

When mapping this site in IIS, you should not run into problems because length exceeds 260 chars.